# Issue rendering PDF with ActiveReports7

Tags: activereports, componentone

I have this report that can't be rendered properly to PDF using ActiveReports7.0. It used to be working correctly with ActiveReports3.0. The error log I'm getting is as follows.

```
at #mqc.#Aqc.#rn() 
at #mqc.#8qc.#7Zc(Stream stream, #1rc securityInfo) 
at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport.#7pk(SectionDocument document, Stream stream, String pageRange) 
at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport.Export(SectionDocument document, Stream stream, String pageRange) 
at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport.Export(SectionDocument document, String filePath, String pageRange) 
at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Section.PdfExport.Export(SectionDocument document, String filePath)
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "it used to work properly"? When did it stop, and what changed to make it stop?

Comment: It is working with AR3.0. Started to not work when we upgraded to AR7.0 Grapecity

Comment: @Meanne..You may want to send your report's RDF file to Grapecity support. You may post it here (http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/88/ShowForum.aspx). For more information on saving RDF files, please check this link ("http://bit.ly/17gCZt9").

Comment: @Meanne You gave the stack trace but not the error/exception. Can you please provide the full exception details?

Comment: Got it figured out. The report that's being added to the main report has an exception that's why it's got nothing to render.